# how to check if any of the value in a column is null it shld count value 1 in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how  to check if any of the value in a column is null it shld count value 1 in mongoose?
i tried

```
data: {
                        $max: {
                            $cond: [{
                                $or: [{ $eq: ["$mycolumn", null] },
                                    // { $eq: [ "$anotherField","value"] }
                                ]
                            },
                                0,
                                1]
                        }

               },
```

but this is returning null.how to fix this?Thanks in advance

my collection is

```
{ _id: 1, item: null ,name:sam,status:open},
{ _id: 2, item: null ,name:arun,status:open},
{ _id: 2, item: 1,name:arun,status:close},
{ _id: 2, item: 1,name:sam,status:close},
```

also i have to retrieve by grouping status.

Comment: Please share collection

Comment: i have updated.i need to check if any one of the value in item column is null then count should be calculated.

Comment: Please use that code for set item value set 1 if item is null 
db.demo.aggregate({ "$addFields": {
        "item":  
          {
             $ifNull: [ '$item', 1 ] 
          }
       } } );

Comment: yes i tried By using addFields suggested by @mahesh Bhatnagar.works fine now.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{$group: {_id : '$status',
   sumOfItem : {$sum : {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$item", null ] }, 1, '$item' ]}}}}])

 (Or)

/** If you've to check if field exists & also field value == null to return 1 
    or original item value try below - but this might not be needed,
    if you don't want to check field exists cause `$ifNull` internally does both checks */
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{$group: {_id : '$status', sumOfItem : {$sum : { $ifNull: [ "$item", 1 ] }}}}])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "item" : null,
    "name" : "sam",
    "status" : "open"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "item" : null,
    "name" : "arun",
    "status" : "open"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3.0,
    "item" : 1.0,
    "name" : "arun",
    "status" : "close"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 4.0,
    "item" : 1.0,
    "name" : "sam",
    "status" : "close"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : 5.0,
    "item" : 3,
    "name" : "sam3",
    "status" : "open"
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "close",
    "sumOfItem" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "open",
    "sumOfItem" : 5.0
}
```

Just in case if you don't want sum of item field but just want total `open` & `close` statuses(you don't have to check for `null`) then try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{$group: {_id : '$status', total : {$sum : 1}}}])


**Result :**

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "close",
    "total" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "open",
    "total" : 3.0
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much @srinivasy.This also works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

By using **addFields** , We can set 1 value of item if item is null after count the status

```
db.demo.aggregate(
    [{ "$addFields": {
        "item":  
          {
             $ifNull: [ '$item', 1 ] 
          }

       },
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
            _id:  '$status' ,
            count: { '$sum': '$item' },
        }
    }
   ]);
```

Comment: Marked answer if you like